# resource-optimization-with-maven-resources in rich faces 4.3.1.Final

Tags: jsf, richfaces, maven-3

I have read a blog from jboss community https://community.jboss.org/people/michpetrov/blog/2012/11/27/resource-optimization-with-maven-resources-plugin but is there anyway I can redirect the path richfaces is looking for the skinning.css and Packed.css to look for my custom files. Please help thanks

Comment: I think we are sharing the same problem - did you find any solution? I asked about the same thing in RichFaces forum https://community.jboss.org/thread/229609?tstart=0